# Variance of convex set less than variance of non-convex set?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $F(\cdot)$ be a CDF, let $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a non-convex set that lies fully in the support of $F(\cdot)$ and let $x \sim F(\cdot)$. I have a convex set $S' \subset \mathbb{R}$ (also in the support of $F(\cdot)$) that satisfies $E[x|x \in S'] = E[x|x \in S]$ and $\int_{x \in S} dF(x) = \int_{x \in S'} dF(x)$. How do I show that $Var(x|x \in S') < Var(x| x \in S)$?